# Regex match digits, comma and semicolon?

Tags: java, regex

What's a regular expression that will match a string only containing digits 0 through 9, a comma, and a semi-colon? I'm looking to use it in Java like so:

```
word.matches("^[1-9,;]$") //Or something like that...
```

I'm new to regular expressions.

Comment: Well, you're close - what do you think `1-9` does?

Comment: `1-9` probably won't match 0 through 9 as well as `0-9` will, other than that ...

Comment: Woah, thanks everyone.  Must have been too easy.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You almost have it, you just left out 0 and forgot the quantifier.

```
word.matches("^[0-9,;]+$")
```

Answer (score 37):

You are 90% of the way there.

`^[0-9,;]+$`

Starting with the carat `^` indicates a beginning of line.

The `[` indicates a character set

The `0-9` indicates characters 0 through 9, the comma `,` indicates comma, and the semicolon indicates a `;`.

The closing `]` indicates the end of the character set.

The plus `+` indicates that one or more of the "previous item" must be present.  In this case it means that you must have one or more of the characters in the previously declared character set.

The dollar `$` indicates the end of the line.

Comment: I think ^ $ can also means the beginning and the end of any input (can be a whole text file as a long long string), not necessarily of a line . But this feature depends on the implementation of Regular Expression.

Comment: If someone decided to make a regular expression language where '^$' means any input, then why even bother with the dot '.' and star '*' operators?  I'm not doubting that someone might do it, but it basically means you can't match empty lines (which is dumb).

Comment: [see this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)  "Therefore, all the regex engines discussed in this tutorial have the option to expand the meaning of both anchors. "  ^ matches the beginning of a string and $ matches the end of a string.
So it is an option to make them match the beginning and the end of a line, but this option is not a recommendation.

Comment: @Gab That seems to focus on Perl regex and a couple of compatible "extension" GNU features, which might be heavily used; but, far from the only way to do it.  In fact, there are many similar, but subtly different ways one can construct the "input string" to setup the regex.  The actual mechanics of the regex matching is controlled by generated DFA, which (for those who don't know) is a Math construct, so really the "engine" can only perform one way (notwithstanding bugs).  Looks like the extension eases the matching of whole lines, at the expense of making it difficult to capture empty lines.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Empty lines can be captured via /(^|\n)(\n|$)/ expressions.  Or, using PCRE, via the /m modifier (ie: /^$/m).  In addition, the /s modifier makes it so that the . character class matches even \n, allowing it to gather characters across lines.  There are a lot of gotcha's in regexes, but that isn't one of them.

Answer (score 6):

Try `word.matches("^[0-9,;]+$");`

Answer (score 5):

`word.matches("^[0-9,;]+$");` you were almost there

Answer (score 2):

You current regex will only match 1 character. you need either * (includes empty string) or + (at least one) to match multiple characters and numbers have a shortcut : \d (need \\ in a string).

```
word.matches("^[\\d,;]+$")
```

The Pattern documentation is pretty good : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Also you can try your regexps online at:
http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean foundMatch = Pattern.matches("[0-9,;]+", "131;23,87");
```